# Objects clipping when I switch to orthographic mode Blender 2.8

Tags: orthographic

So, every time I switch to orthographic mode in Blender 2.8 (Didn't use to happen in 2.79) my model starts clipping (as shown in the video). I've tried changing the "clip start" value, but that just ruins it when I switch back over to the dynamic view.

Any ideas?

Video: https://youtu.be/EuOuOvNPw78

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem and fortunately we are not alone and somebody has already reported this bug. You can find the current state of it at the link below. It looks like it's been resolved and we're just waiting on an update now.

Bug report
https://developer.blender.org/T61632

Specific commit with the fix
https://developer.blender.org/rB4bbd1b9610f6d85079ea5bc31fc1949f8409a1a4

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Thank you for contributing. =)
I upvoted your answer since it resolves the question. Bug questions should however be flagged for closure instead of answered.

Comment: Aaah okay so should I flag it or can I assume you've already done this? I'm still learning so I appreciate the tip. :)

Comment: In this case, I've already done it, but there is no harm in flagging twice. There are several cases when question should be flagged, because the answer will not hold up for a long time. [More on closing question here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for answering. I'll wait for the patch then :)

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know that the update is out and ortho view is working as expected. It's up on the Blender 2.8 download page now in case you haven't checked it yet.

Comment: Cool! I'll have a look inmediatelly.

Answer (score 0):

set it up like in this capture, thats its the right values [image]